# Extracting columns with a difference in aligned data

Tags: python-2.7

I have some aligned data (something bioinformatic related) as so:

```
reference_string = 'yearning'
string2 = 'learning'
string3 = 'aligning'
```

I need to extract only columns showing differences in relation to the reference data.
The output should show only positional information of the columns containing differences in relation to the reference string and the corresponding reference item.

```
       1 2 3 4
       y e a r
       l
       a l i g
```

My current code does most things okay except that it also reports columns with no difference.

```
string1 = 'yearning'
string2 = 'learning'
string3 = 'aligning'

string_list = [string1, string2]

reference = reference_string
diffs_top, diffs = [], []
all_diffs = set()

for s in string_list:
    diffs = []
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if s[i] != reference[i]:
            diffs.append(i)
            all_diffs.add(i)
    diffs_top.append(diffs)

for d in all_diffs:
    print str(int(d+1)),
print

for c in reference:
    print str(c),
print

for i, s in enumerate(string_list):
    for j, c in enumerate(s):
        if j in diffs_top[i]:
            print str(c),
        else:
            print str(' '),
    print
```

This code would give:

```
1 2 3 4
y e a r n i n g

l              
a l i g
```

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT:** I have picked some section of real data to make the problem as clearer as possible and my attempt at solving it thus far:

```
reference_string = 'MAHEWGPQRLAGGQPQAS'
string1 = 'MAQQWSLQRLAGRHPQDS'
string2 = 'MAQRWGAHRLTGGQLQDT'
string3 = 'MAQRWGPHALSGVQAQDA'

string_list = [string1, string2, string3]

reference = reference_string
diffs_top, diffs = [], []
all_diffs = set()

for s in string_list:
    diffs = []
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if s[i] != reference[i]:
            diffs.append(i)
            all_diffs.add(i)
    diffs_top.append(diffs)
#print diffs_top
#print all_diffs

for d in all_diffs:
    print str(int(d+1)), # retains natural positions of the reference residues
print

for d in all_diffs:
    for i, c in enumerate(reference):
        if i == d:
            print c,
print
```

The print out will be an output showing the position at which there is any difference to other non-reference strings and the corresponding reference letter.

```
3 4 6 7 8 9 11 13 14 15 17 18
H E G P Q R A G Q P A S
```

Then the next step is to write a code that will process non reference strings by printing out the difference with the reference (at that position). If there is no difference it will leave blank (' ').

Doing it manually the output will be:

```
3 4 6 7 8 9 11 13 14 15 17 18
H E G P Q R  A  G  Q  P  A  S
Q Q S L         R  H     D  
Q R   A H    T        L  D  T
Q R     H A  S  V     A  D  A
```

My entire code as an attempt to get to the solution above as been messy to say the least:

```
reference_string = 'MAHEWGPQRLAGGQPQAS'
string1 = 'MAQQWSLQRLAGRHPQDS'
string2 = 'MAQRWGAHRLTGGQLQDT'
string3 = 'MAQRWGPHALSGVQAQDA'

string_list = [string1, string2, string3]

reference = reference_string
diffs_top, diffs = [], []
all_diffs = set()

for s in string_list:
    diffs = []
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if s[i] != reference[i]:
            diffs.append(i)
            all_diffs.add(i)
    diffs_top.append(diffs)
#print diffs_top
#print all_diffs

for d in all_diffs:
    print str(int(d+1)),
print

for d in all_diffs:
    for i, c in enumerate(reference):
        if i == d:
            print c,
print

# this is my attempt to look into non-reference strings
# to check for the difference with the reference, and print an output.
for d in all_diffs:
    for i, s in enumerate(string_list):
        for j, c in enumerate(s):
            if j == d:
                print c,
            else:
                print str(' '),
print
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working perfectly fine (as per your logic).

What is happening , is that while printing the output, when you come across the reference string, Python looks for the corresponding entry in the `diffs_top` list and because while storing in `diff_top`, you have no entry stored for the reference string, Python just prints blank spaces for your reference string.

```
1 2 3 4
y e a r n i n g #prints the reference string, because you've coded in that way
                #prints blank as string_list[0] and reference string are the same
l
a l i g
```

The question here is how exactly do you define your difference for reference string.

Besides, I also found some fundamental flaws in your code implementation. If you try to run your code by setting `string_list[1]` as your reference string, you would get your output as :

```
1 2 3 4
l e a r n i n g
y

a l i g
```

Is this what you need? Please spend some time in properly defining difference for all cases and then try to implement you code.

**EDIT:**

As per you updated requirements, replace the last block in your code with this:

```
for i, s in enumerate(string_list):
    for d in all_diffs:
        if d in diffs_top[i]:
            print s[d],
        else:
            print ' ',
    print
```

Cheers!

Comment: I have made some explanation plus follow-up attempt to make my problem clearer. Please check in to see if you can help.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a general problem in your logic. If you need to extract only columns showing difference in relation to the reference data and `string1` is the reference the output should be:

```
1 2 3 4

l
a l i g
```

So, `'yearning'` shouldn't show any character because it has no difference to `string1`.

If you delete or put the following lines in comments, you will exactly get what I expect is the right answer:

```
#for c in reference:
#    print str(c),
#print
```

Consider to review your logic if this solution is not what you actually want.

---

**Update**

Here is a shorter solution which solves your task:

```
from itertools import compress, izip_longest

def delta(reference, string):
    return [ '' if a == b else b for a, b in izip_longest(reference, string)]    

ref_string = 'MAHEWGPQRLAGGQPQAS'
strings = ['MAQQWSLQRLAGRHPQDS',
           'MAQRWGAHRLTGGQLQDT',
           'MAQRWGPHALSGVQAQDA']

delta_strings = [delta(ref_string, string) for string in strings]
selectors = [1 if any(tup) else 0 for tup in izip_longest(*delta_strings)]
indices = [str(i+1) for i in range(len(selectors))]

output_data = [indices, ref_string] + delta_strings

for line in output_data:
    print ''.join(x.rjust(3) for x in compress(line, selectors))
```

**Explanation:**

- I defined a function `delta(reference, string)` which returns the delta between the string and the referenced string. For example: `delta("ABFF", "AECF")` returns the list `['', E, C, '']`.
- The variable `delta_strings` holds all the deltas between each string in the list `strings` and the reference string `ref_string`.
- The variable `selector` is a list containing only `1` and `0` values, where `0` specifies the collumns which shouldn't be printed and vice versa.

Comment: I corrected the layout of my problem please check for help. Thanks.